# How to do a conditional response with Physics2D.OverlapCircle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to a conditional response using the `Physics2D.OverlapCircle()`. Below is the code I am using. Which basically says, if the overlap is with a layer called "Platform" set grounded to true.

```
public bool grounded;  //true or fals if you are grounded
public Transform groundCheck; //Object which will check if we are grounded


float groundRadius = .2f;  //Radius around ground check object will check if grounded
public LayerMask platform; //Decide which layers count as grounded.


void FixedUpdate()
{
    grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, platform);
}
```

In this case `true == Jump`.

```
if (grounded == true)
{
   //jump
}
```

But I don't always want it to jump.  For example, if the layer is "Ground" I don't want it to jump.

If the layer is"Platform" I do want it to jump.

I can't figure out how to specify which Layer it is overlapping and do something different.

Comment: Can't you just do two checks with `OverlapCircle()`? One for the Ground layer, one for the Platform layer, then execute code accordingly?

Comment: this is what I am going to try to do today.

Comment: All right. If it doesn't work out, be sure to update your question with the new details. And if it does, feel free to post your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

That worked!  Here is the answer.  I just had to set the layers in the inspector to act the way I wanted.

```
public bool platformTouch;  //true or false if touching platform
public Transform groundCheck; //Object which will check if we are grounded

public bool groundedTouch; //true or false if touching ground
public LayerMask ground; //Decide which layers count as grounded.


float groundRadius = .2f;  //Radius around ground check object will check if grounded
public LayerMask platform; //Decide which layers count as grounded.


void FixedUpdate()
{
    platformTouch = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, platform);

    groundedTouch = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, ground);
}
```